# What is the expected latency of data transfer between sockets in localhost?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, low-latency

I am working on a system that needs to have a very low overall latency in execution. For this, I have to make a design choice. One option would be to use a single program that does the entire task, or two separate programs (much more preferable for my use case), the first of which sends relevant data to the other, both of which are implemented on the same host machine.

I am looking to implement the system in Python for now, and transfer to C++ later, both on a Windows machine. For inter-process communication, I am considering sockets. I am trying to get an estimate of what would be the order of magnitude of the latency I should expect in transmitting the data (Usually 5 floating point numbers at a time) from one program to the other.

Comment: WM_COPYDATA message?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the python implementation of ZeroMQ. Sockets would work, but 0MQ is faster and works with multiple languages: https://zeromq.org/languages/python/